# SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, collectionview, xcode12

I was wondering if it is possible to use the `View.onDrag` and `View.onDrop` to add drag and drop reordering within one `LazyGrid` manually?

Though I was able to make every Item draggable using `onDrag`, I have no idea how to implement the dropping part.

[image]

Here is the code I was experimenting with:

```
import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Data

struct Data: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
}

//MARK: - Model

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Data]
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(160)),
        GridItem(.fixed(160))
    ]
    
    init() {
        data = Array<Data>(repeating: Data(id: 0), count: 100)
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            data[i] = Data(id: i)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Grid

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: model.columns, spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(model.data) { d in
                    ItemView(d: d)
                        .id(d.id)
                        .frame(width: 160, height: 240)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .onDrag { return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - GridItem

struct ItemView: View {
    var d: Data
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(d.id))
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Here is completed simple demo of possible approach (did not tune it much, `cause code growing fast as for demo).

[image: demo]

Important points are: a) reordering does not suppose waiting for drop, so should be tracked on the fly; b) to avoid dances with coordinates it is more simple to handle drop by grid item views; c) find what to where move and do this in data model, so SwiftUI animate views by itself.

Tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct GridData: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
}

//MARK: - Model

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [GridData]

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(160)),
        GridItem(.fixed(160))
    ]

    init() {
        data = Array(repeating: GridData(id: 0), count: 100)
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            data[i] = GridData(id: i)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Grid

struct DemoDragRelocateView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()

    @State private var dragging: GridData?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
           LazyVGrid(columns: model.columns, spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(model.data) { d in
                    GridItemView(d: d)
                        .overlay(dragging?.id == d.id ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
                        .onDrag {
                            self.dragging = d
                            return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
                        }
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $model.data, current: $dragging))
                }
            }.animation(.default, value: model.data)
        }
    }
}

struct DragRelocateDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let item: GridData
    @Binding var listData: [GridData]
    @Binding var current: GridData?

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if item != current {
            let from = listData.firstIndex(of: current!)!
            let to = listData.firstIndex(of: item)!
            if listData[to].id != current!.id {
                listData.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from),
                    toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        self.current = nil
        return true
    }
}

//MARK: - GridItem

struct GridItemView: View {
    var d: GridData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(d.id))
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 160, height: 240)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

### Edit

Here is how to fix the never disappearing drag item when dropped outside of any grid item:

```
struct DropOutsideDelegate: DropDelegate { 
    @Binding var current: GridData?  
        
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        current = nil
        return true
    }
}
```

```
struct DemoDragRelocateView: View {
    ...

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ...
        }
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropOutsideDelegate(current: $dragging))
    }
}
```

Comment: That works quite well, however, the dragging state variable is not reset to ni when you drag it out of the v-grid, so that the overlay is on the original item. When you start dragging, the item from which you drag gets the whitish overlay-colour. when you drag it out of the v-grid (not on another item), and then release, it moves back to the original position. however, the whitish overlay stays the same and dragging is never set to nil. I also tried to make this work with Sections but my first attempt has failed.

Comment: @user3122959 I've added an onDrop as well on the ScrollView itself to catch when the dragging ends outside the grid itself, setting dragging to nil when drop is performed.

Comment: The DropOutside delegate works well if you drop outside the views you've defined, but if you drag an item into, say, the navigation title of a Nav View (easy to do by accident), the onDrop is never called and current is never set to nil, so the faded item just sticks there until you drag something else.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Attaching the drop-outside-delegate to the Scroll View works fine.  My ScrollView also has a navigation bar and dropping on the bar does't call the perform drop function but I think it's a minor issue and in most cases it works now.

Comment: Great solution. I would only suggest to make `DragRelocateDelegate` generic so that it is easy to copy-paste :)

Comment: I noticed that when dropping the dragged item on itself (to cancel an accidental drag) it will be invisible because the dragItem does not get set to nil. 

Thoughts on how I could achieve that?

Comment: Should be `[UTType.text]`, not `[UIType.text]`.

Comment: I agree, nice solution, but it didn't save position of reordered page when terminate the app, and it will be tricky trying to use it with documents in directory

Comment: @ViOS you would have to manually update your persisting data if you want it to stay after termination.

Comment: I noticed the DropOutsideDelegate is not called if dropping on 'empty' parts of your generic view. To solve it, add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` before `.onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropOutsideDelegate(current: $dragging))`

Comment: This works pretty good, however there are some problems:
1. If I long press the grid view and don't move my finger, dropEntered(info: DropInfo) is not called. 
2. onDrag is called twice if I add onTapGesture handler.
3. Drag Preview view is not rendered until I move dragged view (It's not shown on long press)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 33):

Here's my solution (based on Asperi's answer) for those who seek for a generic approach for `ForEach` where I **abstracted the view away**:

```
struct ReorderableForEach<Content: View, Item: Identifiable & Equatable>: View {
    let items: [Item]
    let content: (Item) -> Content
    let moveAction: (IndexSet, Int) -> Void
    
    // A little hack that is needed in order to make view back opaque
    // if the drag and drop hasn't ever changed the position
    // Without this hack the item remains semi-transparent
    @State private var hasChangedLocation: Bool = false

    init(
        items: [Item],
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> Content,
        moveAction: @escaping (IndexSet, Int) -> Void
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.content = content
        self.moveAction = moveAction
    }
    
    @State private var draggingItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            content(item)
                .overlay(draggingItem == item && hasChangedLocation ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
                .onDrag {
                    draggingItem = item
                    return NSItemProvider(object: "\(item.id)" as NSString)
                }
                .onDrop(
                    of: [UTType.text],
                    delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(
                        item: item,
                        listData: items,
                        current: $draggingItem,
                        hasChangedLocation: $hasChangedLocation
                    ) { from, to in
                        withAnimation {
                            moveAction(from, to)
                        }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

The `DragRelocateDelegate` basically stayed the same, although I made it a bit more generic and safer:

```
struct DragRelocateDelegate<Item: Equatable>: DropDelegate {
    let item: Item
    var listData: [Item]
    @Binding var current: Item?
    @Binding var hasChangedLocation: Bool

    var moveAction: (IndexSet, Int) -> Void

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        guard item != current, let current = current else { return }
        guard let from = listData.firstIndex(of: current), let to = listData.firstIndex(of: item) else { return }
        
        hasChangedLocation = true

        if listData[to] != current {
            moveAction(IndexSet(integer: from), to > from ? to + 1 : to)
        }
    }
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        hasChangedLocation = false
        current = nil
        return true
    }
}
```

### And finally here is the actual usage:

```
ReorderableForEach(items: itemsArr) { item in
    SomeFancyView(for: item)
} moveAction: { from, to in
    itemsArr.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I've built upon your solution to add support for custom drag previews. You can find the code here: https://github.com/danielsaidi/SwiftUIKit/tree/master/Sources/SwiftUIKit/Lists

Answer (score 7):

There was a few additional issues raised to the excellent solutions above, so here's what I could come up with on Jan 1st with a hangover (i.e. apologies for being less than eloquent):

1. If you pick a griditem and release it (to cancel), then the view is not reset

I added a bool that checks if the view had been dragged yet, and if it hasn't then it doesn't hide the view in the first place. It's a bit of a hack, because it doesn't really reset, it just postpones hiding the view until it knows that you want to drag it. I.e. if you drag really fast, you can see the view briefly before it's hidden.

2. If you drop a griditem outside the view, then the view is not reset

This one was partially addressed already, by adding the dropOutside delegate, but SwiftUI doesn't trigger it unless you have a background view (like a color), which I think caused some confusion. I therefore added a background in grey to illustrate how to properly trigger it.

Hope this helps anyone:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct GridData: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: String
}

//MARK: - Model

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [GridData]

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 60, maximum: 60))
    ]

    init() {
        data = Array(repeating: GridData(id: "0"), count: 50)
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            data[i] = GridData(id: String("\(i)"))
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Grid

struct DemoDragRelocateView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()

    @State private var dragging: GridData? // I can't reset this when user drops view ins ame location as drag started
    @State private var changedView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
               LazyVGrid(columns: model.columns, spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(model.data) { d in
                        GridItemView(d: d)
                            .opacity(dragging?.id == d.id && changedView ? 0 : 1)
                            .onDrag {
                                self.dragging = d
                                changedView = false
                                return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
                            }
                            .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $model.data, current: $dragging, changedView: $changedView))
                            
                    }
                }.animation(.default, value: model.data)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropOutsideDelegate(current: $dragging, changedView: $changedView))
    }
}

struct DragRelocateDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let item: GridData
    @Binding var listData: [GridData]
    @Binding var current: GridData?
    @Binding var changedView: Bool
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        
        if current == nil { current = item }
        
        changedView = true
        
        if item != current {
            let from = listData.firstIndex(of: current!)!
            let to = listData.firstIndex(of: item)!
            if listData[to].id != current!.id {
                listData.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from),
                    toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        changedView = false
        self.current = nil
        return true
    }
    
}

struct DropOutsideDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var current: GridData?
    @Binding var changedView: Bool
        
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        changedView = true
    }
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        changedView = false
        current = nil
        return true
    }
}

//MARK: - GridItem

struct GridItemView: View {
    var d: GridData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(d.id))
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
        .background(Circle().fill(Color.green))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I came with a bit different approach that works fine on macOS. Instead of using `.onDrag` and `.onDrop` Im using `.gesture(DragGesture)` with a helper class and modifiers.

[image]

Here are helper objects (just copy this to the new file):

```
// Helper class for dragging objects inside LazyVGrid.
// Grid items must be of the same size
final class DraggingManager<Entry: Identifiable>: ObservableObject {
    
    let coordinateSpaceID = UUID()
    
    private var gridDimensions: CGRect = .zero
    private var numberOfColumns = 0
    private var numberOfRows = 0
    private var framesOfEntries = [Int: CGRect]() // Positions of entries views in coordinate space
    
    func setFrameOfEntry(at entryIndex: Int, frame: CGRect) {
        guard draggedEntry == nil else { return }
        framesOfEntries[entryIndex] = frame
    }
    
    var initialEntries: [Entry] = [] {
        didSet {
            entries = initialEntries
            calculateGridDimensions()
        }
    }
    @Published // Currently displayed (while dragging)
    var entries: [Entry]?
    
    var draggedEntry: Entry? { // Detected when dragging starts
        didSet { draggedEntryInitialIndex = initialEntries.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == draggedEntry?.id }) }
    }
    var draggedEntryInitialIndex: Int?
    
    var draggedToIndex: Int? { // Last index where device was dragged to
        didSet {
            guard let draggedToIndex, let draggedEntryInitialIndex, let draggedEntry else { return }
            var newArray = initialEntries
            newArray.remove(at: draggedEntryInitialIndex)
            newArray.insert(draggedEntry, at: draggedToIndex)
            withAnimation {
                entries = newArray
            }
        }
    }

    func indexForPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> Int {
        let x = max(0, min(Int((point.x - gridDimensions.origin.x) / gridDimensions.size.width), numberOfColumns - 1))
        let y = max(0, min(Int((point.y - gridDimensions.origin.y) / gridDimensions.size.height), numberOfRows - 1))
        return max(0, min(y * numberOfColumns + x, initialEntries.count - 1))
    }

    private func calculateGridDimensions() {
        let allFrames = framesOfEntries.values
        let rows = Dictionary(grouping: allFrames) { frame in
            frame.origin.y
        }
        numberOfRows = rows.count
        numberOfColumns = rows.values.map(\.count).max() ?? 0
        let minX = allFrames.map(\.minX).min() ?? 0
        let maxX = allFrames.map(\.maxX).max() ?? 0
        let minY = allFrames.map(\.minY).min() ?? 0
        let maxY = allFrames.map(\.maxY).max() ?? 0
        let width = (maxX - minX) / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        let height = (maxY - minY) / CGFloat(numberOfRows)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY)
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        gridDimensions = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    }
        
}

struct Draggable<Entry: Identifiable>: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding
    var originalEntries: [Entry]
    let draggingManager: DraggingManager<Entry>
    let entry: Entry

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let entryIndex = originalEntries.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == entry.id }) {
            let isBeingDragged = entryIndex == draggingManager.draggedEntryInitialIndex
            let scale: CGFloat = isBeingDragged ? 1.1 : 1.0
            content.background(
                GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                    draggingManager.setFrameOfEntry(at: entryIndex, frame: geometry.frame(in: .named(draggingManager.coordinateSpaceID)))
                    return .clear
                }
            )
            .scaleEffect(x: scale, y: scale)
            .gesture(
                dragGesture(
                    draggingManager: draggingManager,
                    entry: entry,
                    originalEntries: $originalEntries
                )
            )
        }
        else {
            content
        }
    }
    
    func dragGesture<Entry: Identifiable>(draggingManager: DraggingManager<Entry>, entry: Entry, originalEntries: Binding<[Entry]>) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .named(draggingManager.coordinateSpaceID))
            .onChanged { value in
                // Detect start of dragging
                if draggingManager.draggedEntry?.id != entry.id {
                    withAnimation {
                        draggingManager.initialEntries = originalEntries.wrappedValue
                        draggingManager.draggedEntry = entry
                    }
                }
                
                let point = draggingManager.indexForPoint(value.location)
                if point != draggingManager.draggedToIndex {
                    draggingManager.draggedToIndex = point
                }
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                withAnimation {
                    originalEntries.wrappedValue = draggingManager.entries!
                    draggingManager.entries = nil
                    draggingManager.draggedEntry = nil
                    draggingManager.draggedToIndex = nil
                }
            }
    }

}

extension View {
    // Allows item in LazyVGrid to be dragged between other items.
    func draggable<Entry: Identifiable>(draggingManager: DraggingManager<Entry>, entry: Entry, originalEntries: Binding<[Entry]>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Draggable(originalEntries: originalEntries, draggingManager: draggingManager, entry: entry))
    }
}
```

Now to use it in view you have to do few things:

- Create a draggingManager that is a `StateObject`
- Create a var that exposes either real array you are using or temporary array used by draggingManager during dragging.
- Apply `coordinateSpace` from draggingManager to the container (LazyVGrid)
  That way draggingManager only modifies its copy of the array during the process, and you can update the original after dragging is done.

  struct VirtualMachineSettingsDevicesView: View {

  ```
    @ObservedObject
    var vmEntity: VMEntity

    @StateObject
    private var devicesDraggingManager = DraggingManager<VMDeviceInfo>()
    // Currently displaying devices - different during dragging.
    private var displayedDevices: [VMDeviceInfo] { devicesDraggingManager.entries ?? vmEntity.config.devices }

    var body: some View {
        Section("Devices") {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 64, maximum: 64))], alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                Group {
                    ForEach(displayedDevices) { device in
                        Button(action: { configureDevice = device }) {
                            device.label
                                .draggable(
                                    draggingManager: devicesDraggingManager,
                                    entry: device,
                                    originalEntries: $vmEntity.config.devices
                                )
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: { configureNewDevice = true }, label: { Label("Add device", systemImage: "plus") })
                }
                .labelStyle(IconLabelStyle())
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: devicesDraggingManager.coordinateSpaceID)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
  ```

  }

Comment: Also I belief this is better approach for reordering - with DragAndDrop you can work between apps. For example if you drag the item with string outside to text editor it would pass this text there. This is not what we want for just reordering items.

Comment: elegant solution! do you mind sharing the VMEntity also? its missing on the code...

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you implement the on drop part. But remember the `ondrop` can allow content to be dropped in from outside the app if the data conforms to the `UTType`. More on [UTTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE).

Add the onDrop instance to your lazyVGrid.

```
           LazyVGrid(columns: model.columns, spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(model.data) { d in
                    ItemView(d: d)
                        .id(d.id)
                        .frame(width: 160, height: 240)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .onDrag { return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString) }
                }
            }.onDrop(of: ["public.plain-text"], delegate: CardsDropDelegate(listData: $model.data))
```

Create a DropDelegate to handling dropped content and the drop location with the given view.

```
struct CardsDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var listData: [MyData]

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // check if data conforms to UTType
        guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.plain-text"]) else {
            return false
        }
        let items = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.plain-text"])
        for item in items {
            _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { data, _ in
                // idea is to reindex data with dropped view
                let index = Int(data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // id of dropped view
                        print("View Id dropped \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Also the only real useful parameter of `performDrop` is `info.location` a CGPoint of the drop location, Mapping a CGPoint to the view you want to replace seems unreasonable. I would think the `OnMove` would be a better option and would make moving your data/Views a breeze. I was unsuccessful to get `OnMove` working within a `LazyVGrid`.

As `LazyVGrid` are still in beta and are bound to change. I would abstain from use on more complex tasks.

Answer (score 5):

## Goal: Reordering Items in HStack

I was trying to figure out how to leverage this solution in SwiftUI for macOS when dragging icons to re-order a horizontal set of items. Thanks to @ramzesenok and @Asperi for the overall solution. I added a CGPoint property along with their solution to achieve the desired behavior. See the animation below.

[image]

Define the point

```
 @State private var drugItemLocation: CGPoint?
```

I used in `dropEntered`, `dropExited`, and `performDrop` DropDelegate functions.

```
func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
    if current == nil {
        current = item
        drugItemLocation = info.location
    }

    guard item != current, 
          let current = current,
          let from = icons.firstIndex(of: current),
          let toIndex = icons.firstIndex(of: item) else { return }

          hasChangedLocation = true
          drugItemLocation = info.location

    if icons[toIndex] != current {
        icons.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: toIndex > from ? toIndex + 1 : toIndex)
    }
}

func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
    drugItemLocation = nil
}

func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
   hasChangedLocation = false
   drugItemLocation = nil
   current = nil
   return true
}
```

For a full demo, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jav-solo/82b16f302a208e679368493126232e55) using Playgrounds

Comment: Hi, if I copy the gist into Playgrounds.app; it crashes when I drag an icon. Using MBP 2015 macOS 12.6.4 and playground Version 4.1 (1676.15), is there something to fix?

Comment: In case of someone reads my previous post; It works when using XCode Playground project, but not in the Playgrounds.app. However there is a drag lag in play, is this delay to avoid or make it shorter?

Answer (score 0):

Really awesome to the answer in the first floor
Here it a bit change from me

1. `overlay(dragging?.id == d.id ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)`

if you want to hide the background under the moved item, use code below instead

```
.opacity(dragging?.id == d.id ? 0 : 1)
```

2. if you don't want to display a green plus icon when drag, use this class to replace the answer by Asperi

```
struct DropOutsideDelegate: DropDelegate { 
    @Binding var current: GridData?  
        
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        current = nil
        return true
    }

    // must add this function to hide the green plus icon when dragging
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
 }
```

finally, really thanks to Asperi