# how to cancel OnDrag in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making drag & drop lazyVGrid.

i did reference this answer

[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

when drag move another item position it working well

but when I long press and not move and drop itself
self.dragging not set to nil

how can I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to do like this.

```
.gesture(DragGesture()
    .onChanged({ value in
                    if value.x == 0 && value.y == 0 {
                        self.dragging = nil
                    }
                    })
)
```