# SwiftUI: `onDrop` overlay not going away in LazyVGrid?

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I am testing out Asperi's great answer to reordering cells:

[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

The issue I have is the overlay does not reset when I simply enter drag mode and then drop in place, see cell 3:

[image]

I am using the exact code as found on the answer. So it seems like this line:

```
.overlay(dragging?.id == d.id ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
```

is not reacting properly?

Any idea how I can make the overlay to update and go back to `clear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is a SwiftUI bug, because in this scenario `onDrag` is called, but `onDrop` is NOT (that's wrong from D&D flow perspective).

A possible workaround is to introduce additional in-progress state that will indicate that D&D really started. (Actually I would think about some refactoring to simplify delegate's interface, but for demo it is ok).

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Here are changes:

```
  @State private var isUpdating = false // in-progress state

  // ...

  .overlay(dragging?.id == d.id && isUpdating ? // << additional condition
     Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)

  // ...

  .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $model.data, 
     current: $dragging, updating: $isUpdating)) // << transfer into delegate

  // ...

  func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
    updating = true      // << indicate that D&D begins

  // ...

  func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    self.updating = false // << D&D finished
```