# SwiftUI: drag drop cell out of view not resetting overlay?

Tags: swiftui

I am using this solution from Apseri:

[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

with this bug fix:

[SwiftUI: `onDrop` overlay not going away in LazyVGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181072/swiftui-ondrop-overlay-not-going-away-in-lazyvgrid/72181964#72181964)

Just for some reference here, the grid snippet looks like this:

```
struct DemoDragRelocateView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()

    @State private var isUpdating = false
    @State private var dragging: GridData?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
           LazyVGrid(columns: model.columns, spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(model.data) { d in
                    GridItemView(d: d)
                        .overlay(dragging?.id == d.id && isUpdating ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
                        .onDrag {
                            self.dragging = d
                            return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
                        }
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $model.data, current: $dragging, updating: $isUpdating))
                }
            }.animation(.default, value: model.data)
        }
        .border(.red)
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropOutsideDelegate(current: $dragging))
    }
}
```

Problem:

when dropping the cell outside of the view, overlay does not reset.

[image]

In this case above the animation show a drop on the navigation bar. Not sure why, but the gif changed the color to black instead of the red, for the scrollview border.

How can detect the drop outside of the view so the overlay can be reset in this case?