# HStack, List, ForEach of VStack not working

Tags: swiftui

I have the following view:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        HStack(
            alignment: .top
        ) {
            // List {
                ForEach(taskLists, id: \.self) { list in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TaskListView(list: list)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                }
                .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                    print("mooooooooove")
                }
            }
        //}
    }
```

So, it is a horizontal stack of several VStacks. This works fine (e.g):

```
■ ■ ■
```

Now, I want to wrap `ForEach` with the `List` to enable the drag-n-drop. When I uncomment the lines in the above code, the view changes to the vertical stack of the inner VStacks, i.e. they are now one above the other:

```
■
■
■
```

How can I use List&ForEach and remain the horizontal stack AND to enable the `onMove()`?

Please note that putting `List` before `HStack` gives the correct view, but the method `onMove` is not being called.

Comment: You can achieve it using LazyVGrid (with one column). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid