# SwiftUI, Is there a way to make the "ondrag" function "touch down" instead of "long touch"?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI, Is there a way to make the "ondrag" function "touch down" instead of "long touch"?

ex) Common example page
[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

help. :-)