# Strange hang on using .onDrag and .onDrop

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use drag and drop to reorder an `HStack`. I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438481

It works, but somehow, there is a lag after dropping the item. I made a simple example that you can test. I am using a M2 with Sonoma 14.2.1:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct TTab: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var tabs = [TTab(name: "Tab 1"), TTab(name: "Tab 2"), TTab(name: "Tab 3")]
    @State var draggingTab: TTab? = nil
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {            
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(self.tabs) { tab in
                    Text(tab.name)
                        .onDrag {
                            self.draggingTab = tab
                            return NSItemProvider(object: "\(tab.id)" as NSString)
                        }
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text],
                                delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(dragging: self.$draggingTab,
                                                               current: tab,
                                                               tabs: self.$tabs))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct DragRelocateDelegate: DropDelegate {
    
    @Binding var dragging: TTab?
    var current: TTab
    @Binding var tabs: [TTab]
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if self.dragging != self.current {
            let from = self.tabs.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == self.dragging!.id })!
            let to = self.tabs.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == self.current.id })!
            if self.tabs[from].id != self.current.id {
                self.tabs.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        self.dragging = nil
        return true
    }
}
```

If I put a `print("finished")` to `performDrop`, there is no lag. There is only a lag in the interface, but I cannot figure it out with Instruments.

Any idea? Is this a bug?

**EDIT**:

I uploaded a gif animation to show the problem (you can see, that after releasing the mouse button, the dragged part will stay there for a second).

[image: example]