SwiftUI DragGesture stops responding when removing the last item in a row of a 2D array mid-gesture
I’m building a SwiftUI view with draggable items organized in a 2D array (array of arrays). I want to allow items to be moved between rows while dragging, specifically moving the item mid-gesture once the drag reaches a certain threshold. However, I’ve encountered an issue where the last item in each row stops responding to the DragGesture, particularly when attempting to move it to another row. This issue doesn’t occur for other items in the row, only the last one.
Additional Context
My actual app is much more complex, but I’ve created this minimal example where I’m able to replicate the issue. In the real application, I’m not using helper flags like doItOnce, and I’ve streamlined this code to illustrate the core problem. Interestingly, if I move items only within the same row (e.g., swapping positions), the gesture and movement work without any issues. This is all happening on iOS 18.1; I’m currently downloading other simulator versions to test on them as well. I can’t use .draggable because my app is more complex and requires that the gesture starts immediately without a long press on the view.
Issue Description
The code above works as expected for all items except the last item in each row. When I attempt to drag the last item in a row and cross the threshold, the drag gesture stops responding, and I can no longer move the item to another row. For other items, everything works fine, and they move correctly mid-gesture.
Question
Why does the DragGesture.onChanged stop responding for the last item in each row, and how can I enable smooth mid-gesture movement without the gesture dropping? Is there a recommended way to handle moving items between rows in a 2D array mid-gesture in SwiftUI?
Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Youtube video
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let text: String
    let id = UUID()
}

struct DragBugView: View {
    @State var array2d: [[Item]] = [
        [.init(text: "1"), .init(text: "2"), .init(text: "3")],
        [.init(text: "4"), .init(text: "5"), .init(text: "6")],
    ]
    @State var doItOnce = true
    @State var translationHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Dragging translation value: \n \(translationHeight)")
            ForEach(array2d.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(array2d[i].indices, id: \.self) { j in
                        Text(array2d[i][j].text)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                                    .onChanged({ value in
                                        translationHeight = value.translation.height
                                        if value.translation.height > 200 && doItOnce {
                                            let temp = array2d[i].remove(at: j)
                                            array2d[0].insert(temp, at: 0)
                                            doItOnce = false
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .onEnded({ value in
                                        doItOnce = true
                                        translationHeight = 0
                                    })
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DragBugView()
}



Your code always inserts the dragged item at the top left of the grid. Is that intentional? If it is, this also works for the last item of each row, so I cannot reproduce your issue (iOS 18.0).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62606907/5133585

Inserting at the beginning is okay as an example, and inserting itself isn’t the issue—that part works. The problem is, if you look at the text that changes after remove and insert, if you keep dragging, onChanged doesn’t trigger anything. Can you reproduce this? Try dragging the last element from the second row, and when you go over a height of 200, keep dragging and check if the text changes. For other elements, it does change. I also checked on iOS 16.4, and it’s the same issue.

The second link you provided requires a long press, and since my app needs an instant reaction, unfortunately, I can’t use that.

I see. That's because the view has moved to a different ForEach. The old view is destroyed (hence the gesture cancelled) and a new view is added to the first row. How about using a LazyVGrid?

But then why doesn't it happen, for example, when we move the second element from the second row?

That's because your id: parameter is inappropriate. If you use a stable id like the array element's value, this happens for all the elements in the second row. If you use the indices, then index "1" (the id of the second item) still exists in the ForEach when you move the second item (even though it is referring to a different view now). It's only when you move the last item, whose index/id is "2", does the id "2" get removed from the ForEach.

Yes, that makes sense. I’ll have to play around with the ids. Alternatively, I might create a temporary view to serve as a preview, and I’ll handle deletion and insertion only on onEnded. Thank you for the help. If you have any other suggestions on how to resolve this, I’d be glad to hear them.

This occurs because the view that is being dragged is removed from the view hierarchy.
ForEach uses its id: parameter (if it has one) to track when to add/remove views. The outer ForEach creates two inner ForEaches, one for each row. The inner ForEaches uses array indices as their ids. This is already a bad idea, given that you are going to re-order the inner arrays' elements. See also: SwiftUI: Why does ForEach need an ID?
Initially, the IDs for the two rows are:
row 1: 0, 1, 2
row 2: 0, 1, 2

The last item of the second row has 2 as its id. When you move it, the ids now become:
row 1: 0, 1, 2, 3
row 2: 0, 1

We see that the id corresponding to the last item in the second row (i.e. 2) has disappeared from the second row. As a result, ForEach removes the view from the second row, cancelling the gesture. Then, the ForEach for the first row adds a new view to itself.
If you move a non-last item, the same change happens, but that item's id will not be removed from the second row, so the gesture keeps going.
As a proof of concept, if you use only one ForEach, and a more appropriate id, such as the id of the Items, the gesture does not get cancelled.
VStack {
    Text("Dragging translation value: \n \(translationHeight)")
    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(minimum: 10, maximum: 50)), count: 3)) {
        let allIndices = array2d.indices.flatMap { i in
            array2d[i].indices.map { j in (i, j) }
        }
        let _ = print("updated")
        let flattened = array2d.flatMap { $0 }
        ForEach(Array(flattened.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (i, elem) in
            Text(elem.text)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            translationHeight = value.translation.height
                            if value.translation.height > 200 && doItOnce {
                                let (j, k) = allIndices[i]
                                let temp = array2d[j].remove(at: k)
                                array2d[0].insert(temp, at: 0)
                                doItOnce = false
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            doItOnce = true
                            translationHeight = 0
                        })
                )
        }
    }
}

